# Populate a ComboBox on MainForm via Logic.cs

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I was able to populate a comboBox via StreamReader on the MainForm. I find now that I will need that same information in several different comboBox's on different dialog's. This works accept that I can't seem to be able to get at the comboBox "cbTask". Error states "The name 'cbTask' does not exist in the current context". The code

```
    public static void TaskPopulate()
    {

        try
        {
            StreamReader task = new StreamReader(dataFolder + TasksFile);
            string tasks = task.ReadLine();

            while (tasks != null)
            {
                cbTask.Items.Add(tasks);
                tasks = task.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

dataFolder is the path and TasksFile is the file name. Works good if I leave it on the MainForm.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?? Thanks for viewing in advance!! I appreciate it. Have a Great Day!!

EDIT: After reading over this a few times it looks like my question is not clear. I'm trying to add information from the StreamReader to multiple comboBoxes on multiple child dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer provided an Enterprise-style solution, so here is another approach if you wanted a simpler and less expansive way to handle your challenge.

```
public static class MyTaskComboBoxPopulater()
{
    public static void LoadTasksToCombobox(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        try
            {
                StreamReader task = new StreamReader(dataFolder + TasksFile);
                string tasks = task.ReadLine();

                while (tasks != null)
                {
                    comboBox.Items.Add(tasks);
                    tasks = task.ReadLine();
                }    
            }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}

public Form MainForm()
{
    public static void TaskPopulate()
    {
        MyTaskComboBoxPopulater.LoadTasksToCombobox(cbTask);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is brilliant. I'm hoping I can figure it out for 3 more. :) So that I understand, if you have time, the temp variable 'combobox' holds the list and then when I make the call in MainForm it adds those items to cbTask? I actually had to change the call from public static void to private void so I did not have everything at the onLoad call. Thank You Thank You very very much. Have a Great Day!!

Answer (score 1):

Move it to a new Service, and depend on the Service reference for whichever Form you need.

Sample code:

```
public class MyService()
{
    public IEnumerable<string> LoadTasks()
    {
        var taskList = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            StreamReader task = new StreamReader(dataFolder + TasksFile);
            string tasks = task.ReadLine();

            while (tasks != null)
            {
                taskList.Add(tasks);
                tasks = task.ReadLine();
            }    
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return taskList;
    }
}

public Form MainForm()
{
    private MyService _myService = new MyService();

    public static void TaskPopulate()
    {
        foreach(var task in _myService.LoadTasks())
        {
            cbTask.Items.Add(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is where I was just headed. Trying to exclude cbTask from the logic and just call tasks from TaskPopulate(). Seems like a lot of work. the code that I have in it's entirety would be nearly as short to call in each individual winForm. The contents of the comboBox comes from the file I'm reading so seems like a waste. Anyone else?? @Silas

Comment: There's another difference that matters from a design perspective. While you could populate the ComboBox directly, that will couple your Application logic to UI concerns. That will make it hard to change the UI in the future. If you decouple the Application logic from the UI then you only have one place where you have to maintain the logic, and it won't have to change if you add new Forms or changes how the UI uses the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that method in the main window or in a seperate class? If it is in a seperate class, that might explain why "cbTask" Cannot be found.

Also, try using something similar to this `string variable = otherForm.TextBox1.Text;`

Comment: I believe that cbTask can not be found because it currently exists in Form1.cs I'm trying to access it in WidgetLogic.cs. That is where TaskPopulate() resides. I access it when Form1.cs loads with WidgetLogic.TaskPopulate();

Comment: @FrankPytel Try calling the class before you write the method. Such as `textBox1.Text = otherForm.TextBox1.Text;`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288422(v=vs.71).aspx